# If $(D^2+2\zeta \cdot D + q) r= f$ has solution $r$, then what does it mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $(D^2+2\zeta \cdot D + q) r= f$ has  solution $r$, then what does it mean?

$D^2$ is the Laplacian, $D=\nabla$, $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}^n$, $q \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

I wonder if it's the same as in DEs, that plugging in $r$ will make the equation have equal sides?

Would it be wrong to then say that $r=\frac{f}{(D^2+2\zeta \cdot D +q)}$?

Comment: Not really. You can't just divide by an operator.

Comment: @Botond then what? $r$ is a function that, when passed through the operations, produces $f$?

Comment: Maybe you can say that $r=(D^2+2\zeta D+q)^{-1}f$, but I'm not sure, because I this inverse is not unique.

Comment: My notes give an example that $(D^2+2 \zeta \cdot D) G_{\zeta}=I$, where $G_{\zeta}$ is a "solution operator".

Comment: Could you explain what so you mean?

Comment: @Botond Well the example I gave implies that $r$ must be $r=G_{\zeta}f$ (when $q=0$).

Comment: Didn't you miss out the $q$?

Comment: I did write the same, when $(D^2+2\zeta D +q)r=f$, you can multiply both sides (from the left) by the inverse of the operator to get $r=(D^2+2\zeta D +q)^{-1}f$. Note that $(D^2+2\zeta D +q)^{-1}=G_{\zeta}$.